# With Xpath, find the leafiest table node that contains an input box with id="userid"

Tags: html, xml, xhtml, xpath

I've tried a couple of different variations, but I can't seem to get this right.  Given html like:

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
   <tr>
       <td>
           <table>                               <-- I want this table
              <tr>
                  <td><input type="text" id="foo"/></td>
              </tr>
           </table>
       </td>
   </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to find the inner table.

I've tried like //table/*/input[@id='foo'] but I don't get the right things - doesn't anyone have a quick fix for me?  :-)

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested:

```
//input[@id='foo']/ancestor::table[1]
```

Comment: It should be `//input[@id='foo']/ancestor::table[1]` : positional predicate works **on axis direction**.

Comment: @Alejandro: ack, sounds about right (not in a position to test), edited the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Other approach:

```
//table[not(.//table)][.//input[@id='foo']]
```